# jQuery with space

Tags: jquery, image, keypress, space

Please take look at the sample code :

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alidad/5Agu9/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#preview').hide();
    $("#photo").click(update);
    $("#title").keypress(update);
});

function update() {
    $('#preview').slideDown('slow');
    var title = $("#title").val();
    var photo = $("#photo").val();
    $('#Displaytitle').html(title);
    $('#image').html('<img src="' + photo + '"/>');
}​
```

What they do is that when select images drop menu and title name about the images, the title name and images show on the same line (first title and second image).

The problem I have is that please play slow keypress as you can see when you pressed first key it will not show on the text box but then if you pressed second key it will show letter form first key that you pressed it.

What I want is that the title name and images to be together and No SPACE between the two (title name and keyword).

How can I solve that to put together without showing space, I think it is from keypress event, but not sure what it is!

Comment: You should include your code/html in the question, a link to jsfiddle is uselsss if jsfiddle goes down or is blocked in x network(both of which are common)

Comment: This question perfectly demonstrates the difference between syntax and semantics. Syntactically this seems to be English, but semantically, I have no Idea what language that is.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly than this must be the solution 
http://jsfiddle.net/5Agu9/12/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#preview').hide();    
$("#photo").click(update);
    $("#title").on('keyup keypress',update);
});

function update(){        

$('#preview').slideDown('slow');
var title = $("#title").val();
var photo = $("#photo").val();
$('#Displaytitle').html(title+'<img src="'+photo+'"/>');

}
```

You used [keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) but you need to use [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)
 and to merge title and photo's values you need to use +

Comment: keypress() is now keyup() and #DisplayTitle now concantenates title+photo

Comment: dont introduce another closure in there, do `$("#title").on('keyup keypress', update);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the jQuery keyup function instead of the keypress function. http://api.jquery.com/keyup/